# How to upload .deb files using the jenkins pipeline and your credentials to the Nexus OSS

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, nexus, deb

I I’m trying to use the Nexus repository to manage *.deb packages generated by jenkins, but when trying to upload these packages to nexus I’m getting a lot of errors, what is the best way to publish the packages in deb format that are in jenkins to a nexus repository apt, using the jenkins credential management mechanism to authenticate?

Using “Nexus Repository Manager Publisher” the apt repository does not appear, only maven repositories appear.

Tentei usar os seguintes scripts de pipeline:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '3e4ea258-4b41-4379-a0fe-4462ed3e420a', passwordVariable: 'NEXUS_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'NEXUS_USERNAME')]) {
  sh '''
    for i in `/workspace/*.deb`
    do
        echo "Sending $i\r\n"
        curl -u \"$NEXUS_USERNAME:$NEXUS_PASSWORD\" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --data-binary \"@/$i\" "http://10.224.50.202:8081/repository/nerd4ever-labs/"
    done
  '''
}


withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '3e4ea258-4b41-4379-a0fe-4462ed3e420a', passwordVariable: 'NEXUS_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'NEXUS_USERNAME')]) {
  sh '''
    for i in `/workspace/*.deb`
    do
        echo "Sending $i\r\n"
        curl -u $(NEXUS_USERNAME):$(NEXUS_PASSWORD) --upload-file $i "http://10.224.50.202:8081/repository/nerd4ever-labs/"
    done
  '''
}
```

With the above pipelines I get the error:

: Syntax error: newline unexpected

It’s my first contact with the Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager, I’m using an OSS 3.32.0-03 version.

I plan to use it for apt (debian), yum (centos) and poudriere (freebsd) and composer packages, but I’m struggling with the basics.

I’ve already set up the apt repository.

Comment: `Syntax error: newline unexpected` suggests the error is in your jenkins pipeline and that you did not get a chance to contact Nexus. Your curl tries look both quite weird. Here is one I use to test a nexus role and that is working correctly: https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/master/molecule/test_apt_repo.py#L68.

Answer (score 2):

Hello the solution is:

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# Script para subir .DEB's en el nexus repo.
#
# @author   Luis Felipe <lfelipe1501@gmail.com>
# @website  https://www.lfsystems.com.co
# @version  1.0

nexusURL="https://nexus.localhost"

FILES="$(ls workspace)"
for df in $FILES
do
    echo "Processing $df"
    curl -u "$NEXUS_USERNAME:$NEXUS_PASSWORD" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --data-binary "@workspace/$df" "$nexusURL/repository/apt-focal/"
done
```

whit this you can upload all debs files inside the folder that you want.